# what are the alternatives/disadvantages of angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I know angular CLI has great benefits like automating the development process,increasing the productivity,built in support for development(web pack).

but what are the other alternatives to CLI.

Answer (score 2):

There are no alternatives that I'm aware of other than doing everything manually. You could start with some boiler plate code from somewhere and manually build/test/deploy your app.

I know of no real disadvantages.

Have you run into issues? I'm curious what is prompting this question.

Comment: i am sure there might be alternatives to angular CLI. along with CLI i just  want to try the different options.

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI slows down the build time & serve time when project size is large enough.